# JS - How to add a button into a div with appendChid

Tags: javascript

I want to create a sidebar using only JavaScript, but I can't add the close button to the div.
I tried this:

```
var sideb = document.createElement("Div");
    sideb.style.height = "100%";
    sideb.style.width = "0px";
    sideb.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(30,30,30)";
    sideb.style.top = "0px";
    sideb.style.right = "0px";
    sideb.style.margin = "0px";
    sideb.style.padding = "0px";
    sideb.style.position = "fixed"

    document.body.appendChild(sideb);

var close = document.createElement("Button");
    close.innerText = "close";
    close.onclick = close;

    document.body.sideb.appendChild(close)
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.body.sideb.appendChild(close)
```

`body` doesn't have a property/key called `sideb`

you just need

```
sideb.appendChild(close)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of bugs in your code.  Did you make a function called `close`?  I ask this because you're assigning `close` to the `onclick` handler of the button, but after you defined `close` to be the button element in the local scope.  If not, you have to write a function to actually "close" the `div`.  Also, as another person pointed out, `sideb` is not a property of `document.body`.  You can just call `sideb`'s `appendChild` method to add the button.

```
var sideb = document.createElement("Div");
sideb.style.height = "100%";
sideb.style.width = "0px";
sideb.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(30,30,30)";
sideb.style.top = "0px";
sideb.style.right = "0px";
sideb.style.margin = "0px";
sideb.style.padding = "0px";
sideb.style.position = "fixed";

document.body.appendChild(sideb);

var close = document.createElement("Button");
close.innerText = "close";
close.onclick = function() {
    sideB.parentNode.removeChild(sideB);
};

sideb.appendChild(close);
```

Also, if you want to remove some code duplication, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to remove all the extra references to `sideb.style`.

```
Object.assign(sideb.style, {
    height: "100%",
    width: "0px",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(30,30,30)",
    top: "0px",
    right: "0px",
    margin: "0px",
    padding: "0px",
    position: "fixed"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

document.body.sideb in this form mean that you call a property called sideb , there is no sideb in your body object so just use sideb.appendChild()

```
var sideb = document.createElement("Div");
sideb.style.height = "100%";
sideb.style.width = "0px";
sideb.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(30,30,30)";                 sideb.style.top = "0px";
sideb.style.right = "0px";
sideb.style.margin = "0px";
sideb.style.padding = "0px";
sideb.style.position = "fixed"
document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(sideb);
var close = document.createElement("Button");
close.innerText = "close";
close.onclick = close;
sideb.appendChild(close)
```

Comment: Quentin comment decoded. Please  write few lines about your answer instead of just giving working codes.